# Decorating angularJS directive controller function with controllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, decorator

I'm trying to change the behaviour of a specific vendor directive by using $provide.decorator.

The base directive looks something like this:

```
angular
    .module('vendor.module')
    .controller('vendorCtrl', [$scope, function($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.baseFunction = function() {
            //code I want to replace
        }
    }])

    .directive('vendorDir', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'vendorCtrl as vm',
        scope: {
          stuff: '='
        },
        bindToController: true
      }
    }

    // and this is my decorator
angular
    .module('vendor.module')
    .config(function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('vendorDirDirective', function($delegate) {
            var directive;
            directive = $delegate[0];

            // how to override vm.baseFunction ?
            return $delegate;
        });
    }
```

My code sucessfully runs when the other directive starts up, but I'm unsure of what to do to replace functions inside the controller. Trying $scope.baseFunction = function() {} did not work.

How can I change the behaviour of this function?

Comment: A decorator will alter the _return_ value of a method so you could write out your controller more formally in a separate file, and decorate that one method.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```js
var _baseFunction = scope.baseFunction;
function baseFunctionExtended() {
    _baseFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("yay, I'm modified one!");
}
scope.baseFunction = baseFunctionExtended;
```

This will allow to call original function, or not if not needed, and add something more. Next question is how to reach that. I would like to try to extend link function like above.